# javascript: Does Array.sort() fail on large arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Does Array.sort() fail on large arrays? Or did I miss something? I also checked that I'm not sorting strings by mistake. I can't seem to understand why this fails

Pasting directly from Chrome Debugger's Watch:

[image]

And here's something you can play with:

```js
arr = [1.238648000000012,1.5776880000000233,1.6462280000000078,10.007896000000017,10.014455999999996,10.016970000000015,10.018888000000004,10.028069000000016,10.047926000000018,10.056818000000021,10.057980999999984,10.075353000000007,10.086242000000027,10.088684999999998,10.097217,10.102441999999996,10.104630999999983,10.107723000000021,10.108536000000015,10.115552999999977,10.137179000000003,10.171389999999974,10.203172999999992,10.208004000000017,10.217614000000026,10.231874000000005,10.241456000000028,10.243750999999975,10.252985000000024,10.255207999999982,10.27183500000001,10.30159500000002,10.342756000000008,10.35523599999999,10.364777000000004,10.391841,10.40662900000001,10.422856000000024,10.428019000000006,10.438702999999975,10.493548999999973,10.495686999999975,10.522063000000003,10.541649000000007,10.577163999999982,10.605306999999982,10.614864000000011,10.63799899999998,10.677408000000014,10.677971000000014,10.678615999999977,10.683666000000017,10.697460999999976,10.702691000000016,10.738349000000028,10.748320999999976,10.783839,10.834334000000013,10.843086000000028,10.862792000000013,10.893118000000015,10.905455000000018,10.906916000000024,10.923288000000014,10.958798999999999,10.999311999999975,11.003940999999998,11.01112999999998,11.011986999999976,11.022662000000025,11.030069000000026,11.033493000000021,11.06088699999998,11.089207999999985,11.120248000000004,11.169981000000007,11.22742599999998,11.373028999999974,11.38974300000001,11.406037000000026,11.422123,11.445996999999977,11.445996999999977,11.452351000000021,11.45395400000001,11.455066999999985,11.530115000000023,11.563641000000018,11.649070999999992,11.681149000000005,11.699284999999975,11.715215,11.786181,11.798755000000028,11.912154999999984,11.914702999999975,11.92000999999999,11.925179000000014,11.989391000000012,12.065800000000024,12.077261000000021,12.144492000000014,12.213693999999975,12.22724199999999,12.244993000000022,12.293795999999986,12.337166000000025,12.366329000000007,12.42165799999998,12.511757999999986,12.57682699999998,12.583461,12.612408000000016,12.616739999999993,12.662854999999979,12.663344999999993,12.663866999999982,12.673579000000018,12.727368000000013,12.738046999999995,12.748396000000014,12.768007000000011,12.853508999999974,12.860353999999973,12.884284999999977,12.900110999999981,12.92121800000001,12.976439000000028,12.98437100000001,13.01056299999999,13.012036000000023,13.055876000000012,13.138213000000007,13.13959699999998,13.147134999999992,13.156939000000023,13.171355000000005,13.223600999999974,13.240787000000012,13.26833499999998,13.271131999999994,13.272153000000003,13.291954999999973,13.307935999999984,13.41423500000002,13.417280000000005,13.43734999999998,13.448892,13.489640000000009,13.490972,13.491602999999998,13.502335000000016,13.532481000000018,13.55182000000002,13.555890999999974,13.578921999999977,13.580539999999985,13.652214000000015,13.662713999999994,13.674057000000005,13.722780999999998,13.781020000000012,13.790301,13.801070999999979,13.801070999999979,13.826026000000013,13.843449000000021,13.974924999999985,14.012158,14.02240599999999,14.041520999999989,14.088280999999995,14.189909,14.226448000000005,14.288890999999978,14.298192000000029,14.36671100000001,14.379841999999996,14.459216000000026,14.471633999999995,14.51484099999999,14.527475999999979,14.538589000000002,14.608111000000008,14.72200700000002,14.750081000000023,14.818646999999999,14.847937000000002,14.85942,14.874291000000028,14.987093000000016,15.072758000000022,15.126066999999978,15.220902000000024,15.24462699999998,15.323228000000029,15.434033999999997,15.44965000000002,15.45765799999998,15.519754999999975,15.53459700000002,15.599244999999996,15.611743999999987,15.636731999999995,15.672317000000021,15.752161999999998,15.753962999999999,15.835087999999985,16.102216,16.126821000000007,16.12912,16.158558000000028,16.169849999999997,16.178314,16.188782000000003,16.251914,16.32066900000001,16.33669900000001,16.339541999999994,16.38289900000001,16.408960999999977,16.430653000000007,16.437236999999982,16.44171399999999,16.506533999999988,16.60108200000002,16.630889000000025,16.63222300000001,16.64343200000002,16.661643000000026,16.66319199999998,16.71718199999998,16.729517999999985,16.786464000000024,16.796617000000026,16.80394100000001,16.80713800000001,16.811587999999972,16.82970899999998,16.83151700000002,16.854597000000012,16.913752999999986,16.96798100000001,17.025273000000027,17.02839799999998,17.03959900000001,17.19691899999998,17.388582999999983,17.426383999999985,17.633208000000025,17.72530999999998,17.7765,17.925899000000015,17.985956999999985,18.03461299999998,18.035158000000024,18.33455600000002,18.554474000000027,18.819136000000015,19.294691,19.326833000000022,19.370652000000007,19.391025000000013,19.50171900000001,19.568479000000025,19.721015000000023,19.742188999999996,2.0741820000000075,2.190782000000013,2.414432999999974,2.763974000000019,2.792461000000003,2.9027659999999855,2.9076390000000174,2.9481509999999957,2.958406000000025,20.116471999999987,20.465129999999988,21.20068900000001,21.50477699999999,21.81089800000001,22.290697000000023,22.53896800000001,22.783582000000024,23.24664999999999,23.392704999999978,23.70305000000002,24.176241000000005,24.234451999999976,24.29212100000001,25.152215000000012,25.736550000000022,25.955720999999983,26.245765000000006,26.43552199999999,26.738576000000023,26.738576000000023,263.05566699999997,27.455123000000015,27.954201000000012,28.238260000000025,28.66128900000001,3.0292380000000207,3.031385,3.031385,3.104728000000023,3.105985999999973,3.122132000000022,3.1631780000000163,3.1631780000000163,3.1825150000000235,3.1861999999999853,3.1906769999999938,3.2074680000000058,3.2309399999999755,3.2394219999999905,3.248293999999987,3.2692579999999793,3.288909999999987,3.3179549999999836,3.3348550000000046,3.3937690000000202,3.400891999999999,3.427570000000003,3.46416099999999,3.501057000000003,3.5119619999999827,3.5348280000000045,3.535535999999979,3.541954999999973,3.591132000000016,3.595874999999978,3.629410000000007,3.6372420000000147,3.651020000000017,3.674457000000018,3.6869740000000206,3.788045000000011,3.8290949999999953,3.8317579999999793,3.869131999999979,3.8867349999999874,3.8997770000000287,3.9023500000000126,3.970973000000015,4.004128999999978,4.010781000000009,4.013157999999976,4.02364399999999,4.031284000000028,4.034339999999986,4.069560000000024,4.071885000000009,4.07367099999999,4.1598299999999995,4.1598299999999995,4.168802000000028,4.186954000000014,4.259670000000028,4.301670999999999,4.30785800000001,4.326250000000016,4.32803899999999,4.336463999999978,4.396554999999978,4.39680199999998,4.466684999999984,4.5498230000000035,4.551680999999974,4.572103000000027,4.584344999999985,4.592156999999986,4.637402000000009,4.637402000000009,4.645713999999998,4.661412999999982,4.677417999999989,4.681489999999997,4.6883359999999925,4.693658000000028,4.698712999999998,4.703738999999985,4.722540999999978,4.746127999999999,4.786383999999998,4.895690000000002,4.927435000000003,4.949255999999991,4.955774000000019,4.9658640000000105,4.978013999999973,4.9782599999999775,4.982582999999977,5.010145000000023,5.010145000000023,5.027368000000024,5.050145999999984,5.085066999999981,5.089823000000024,5.127470000000017,5.127541000000008,5.157640000000015,5.197153000000014,5.208763999999974,5.216631000000007,5.220619999999997,5.220917999999983,5.241790999999978,5.243516,5.298768999999993,5.302400999999975,5.351732000000027,5.358871000000022,5.395045999999979,5.42818699999998,5.428384999999992,5.440371000000027,5.451302999999996,5.451569000000006,5.453372000000002,5.571251000000018,5.583474000000024,5.603423000000021,5.625193000000024,5.62644499999999,5.6379459999999995,5.639406000000008,5.644623000000024,5.647972999999979,5.654788999999994,5.657871,5.677160000000015,5.684604999999976,5.704746999999998,5.721533000000022,5.754840999999999,5.787960999999996,5.799408000000028,5.836040000000025,5.910754999999995,5.935788000000002,5.98094500000002,5.99198100000001,6.071149999999989,6.167112999999972,6.2217110000000275,6.242680000000007,6.247160000000008,6.299575000000004,6.318251999999973,6.3246240000000284,6.346104000000025,6.390022999999985,6.390474999999981,6.393546000000015,6.406645000000026,6.428521999999987,6.428521999999987,6.4325509999999895,6.474005999999974,6.486009000000024,6.53541899999999,6.588966000000028,6.611136999999985,6.65598,6.661902999999995,6.685046,6.870761000000016,6.897823000000017,6.946781999999985,6.962023999999985,7.0745319999999765,7.079858999999999,7.203704000000016,7.231561999999997,7.396878000000015,7.526357000000019,7.5280500000000075,7.533020000000022,7.540190999999993,7.541165999999976,7.546674999999993,7.567698000000007,7.608597999999972,7.6137899999999945,7.6496609999999805,7.695861999999977,7.754680000000008,7.761375999999984,7.802596999999992,7.803015000000016,7.852875999999981,7.85482300000001,7.881430000000023,7.897682999999972,7.9383980000000065,7.953649999999982,7.977274000000023,7.9786040000000185,8.042038999999988,8.051116999999977,8.058231999999975,8.06355000000002,8.063913000000014,8.065433999999982,8.096699000000001,8.106979000000024,8.11287900000002,8.114483000000007,8.116393000000016,8.123027999999977,8.127981999999975,8.133666000000005,8.133793000000026,8.139561000000015,8.158335000000022,8.16064,8.161336000000006,8.162181999999973,8.162982999999997,8.171137999999985,8.171824000000015,8.176378,8.180379000000016,8.188331000000005,8.19033300000001,8.199669000000029,8.202963000000011,8.205122000000017,8.209947999999997,8.212396000000012,8.214103000000023,8.225754999999992,8.228440999999975,8.236157999999989,8.236670000000004,8.237368000000004,8.246976000000018,8.248426999999992,8.253366000000028,8.257947000000001,8.26767799999999,8.268155999999976,8.272303000000022,8.27318200000002,8.273479000000009,8.275866000000008,8.282681000000025,8.28576099999998,8.287439000000006,8.295105999999976,8.300284999999974,8.301493999999991,8.309056999999996,8.312666999999976,8.313319999999976,8.316741999999977,8.316802999999993,8.319496000000015,8.319905000000006,8.32196399999998,8.33465000000001,8.33758899999998,8.339861999999982,8.343349999999987,8.345591000000013,8.34741600000001,8.351251999999988,8.353306999999973,8.355660999999998,8.35797500000001,8.359123000000011,8.359248999999977,8.361414000000025,8.362278000000003,8.365722000000005,8.367165999999997,8.369223999999974,8.37142399999999,8.372978999999987,8.377184,8.378419000000008,8.380657999999983,8.384374999999977,8.384838000000002,8.38826499999999,8.389519000000007,8.389977999999985,8.391399999999976,8.399541,8.401728999999989,8.40463699999998,8.412535999999989,8.418292000000008,8.418292000000008,8.419540999999981,8.432033999999987,8.436644000000001,8.438633999999979,8.443922999999984,8.445126000000016,8.44520399999999,8.448188000000016,8.454391999999984,8.459992,8.460725000000025,8.471234999999979,8.471527999999978,8.47944799999999,8.481763999999998,8.486855999999989,8.489449999999977,8.48962499999999,8.50250699999998,8.503026999999975,8.505698999999993,8.507151000000022,8.513235000000009,8.521359000000018,8.525622999999996,8.526872000000026,8.529190000000028,8.535190999999998,8.53812499999998,8.539010000000019,8.539371000000017,8.547703000000013,8.54963600000002,8.554725000000019,8.566249000000028,8.56833499999999,8.57478900000001,8.575331000000006,8.59310499999998,8.595698000000027,8.597024999999974,8.603522999999996,8.612051000000008,8.612723000000017,8.621368000000018,8.624873999999977,8.626608999999974,8.631421999999986,8.63256899999999,8.639211999999986,8.647650999999996,8.647655999999984,8.65259900000001,8.666755000000023,8.669451999999978,8.671897999999999,8.673334000000011,8.676539999999989,8.676541999999984,8.686063999999988,8.691044999999974,8.696206000000018,8.706594999999993,8.708612000000016,8.710546000000022,8.713917999999978,8.730766000000017,8.73489699999999,8.737711999999988,8.757464000000027,8.764999999999986,8.809542000000022,8.813491999999997,8.823485000000005,8.834194000000025,8.847305000000006,8.852978000000007,8.855246000000022,8.867098999999996,8.867160000000013,8.871987999999988,8.872235999999987,8.877161999999998,8.884758999999974,8.885359999999991,8.896462999999983,8.938504000000023,8.94348100000002,8.948960999999997,8.988140999999985,9.012393999999972,9.023325,9.029688000000021,9.036518000000001,9.042911000000004,9.042911000000004,9.05015400000002,9.053764999999999,9.077519999999993,9.078524000000016,9.123334,9.125787000000003,9.14443399999999,9.164394000000016,9.177406000000019,9.20016800000002,9.233752999999979,9.236719999999991,9.237805999999978,9.24724500000002,9.256552,9.311277000000018,9.314472000000023,9.324853000000019,9.335095000000024,9.338369,9.34037699999999,9.377050999999994,9.405439999999999,9.414457000000027,9.426608999999985,9.442176000000018,9.445582000000002,9.448505000000011,9.460384999999974,9.460384999999974,9.468001000000015,9.469430999999986,9.469588999999985,9.483652000000006,9.492338000000018,9.507689000000028,9.508412000000021,9.512595999999974,9.51297599999998,9.515115999999978,9.556629999999984,9.560936000000027,9.566130999999984,9.576274000000012,9.582446000000004,9.606822000000022,9.608585000000005,9.615522999999996,9.623440000000016,9.655497000000025,9.685047999999995,9.693380999999988,9.759818999999993,9.788680999999997,9.81468000000001,9.82288699999998,9.829159000000004,9.829363999999998,9.830933000000016,9.835459000000014,9.848674000000017,9.862322000000006,9.877218000000028,9.915767000000017,9.943819000000019,9.944711999999981,9.946091000000024,9.960337999999979,9.976361999999995,9.998279000000025];

output = document.getElementById("output");
output.innerHTML += Math.max(...arr) + '<br />';
output.innerHTML += arr.sort()[arr.length-1] + '<br />';
output.innerHTML += arr.sort()[arr.length-2] + '<br />';
output.innerHTML += arr.sort()[0] + '<br />';

output.innerHTML += '---------------------------------------' + '<br />'

a = [1,2,3,0];
output.innerHTML += Math.max(...a) + '<br />';
output.innerHTML += a.sort()[a.length-1] + '<br />';
output.innerHTML += a.sort()[a.length-2] + '<br />';
output.innerHTML += a.sort()[0] + '<br />';
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='output'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Shouldn't the last element in the sorted array be the max?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: By default `sort` sorts [by strings](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-sortcompare), use a custom sort function to sort by numbers.

Comment: @Teemu Not always, only by default if no `compareFunction` is specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to sort numbers you should pass a call back. If you don't pass a callback it will `sort()` it as strings. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The default `sort` order is built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values.

```js
var array = [1, 10, 100, 20];

array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(...array);

array.sort();
console.log(...array);
```

**Note**:`sort()` modifies the original array. You are using `sort()` like you assume it doesnot. In this case it works fine but maybe in other cases it can cause problems

Comment: But `typeof` returns numbers

Comment: @mbojko no, it's not. with missing cb, you get `[1, 10, 100, 20]`

Comment: So the what all browsers are doing is **convert all numbers to strings** and then sort them? Brilliant!

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran See i have added a documentation. It compares on the basis of `utf-16` codes by default

Comment: I see that there's a point when the datatype of inputs are unknown are not one of the primitive types. But why not check the type by default before switching to default fallback: string?

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran I didn't created javascript.

Comment: @MaheerAli I really wish mate that JS is a project (which it's not) lying in Github which accepts pull requests so we would all get numbers getting sorted as numbers from Chrome 74 and Firefox 67 :D

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran I think the `sort()` function is fine.The thing you are saying will make things more complex and slow. For example what would you think `sort()` without callback should do if you half are number and half elements are strings?

Comment: Don't get me wrong here mate, my suggestion is _not_ to remove the callback, but about what should be there as default in the absence of a callback. I believe `[1,10,2].sort()` should give `[1,2,10]` when fed as numbers, because that's what anyone would intuitively expect it to return.

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran No I am not getting you wrong your question is right.

Answer (score 0):

Math.max called this way will be unreliable. From MDN:

> However, both spread (...) and apply will either fail or return the wrong result if the array has too many elements, because they try to pass the array elements as function parameters. See Using apply and built-in functions for more details. The reduce solution does not have this problem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Comment: There are values bigger than `9.998279000000025` (The value reported by `.sort()`) in the array.